# Is it possible to replace a part of a string with a dynamic 2 way binding?

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, blazor

### Goal

Provided a list of labels (and a moustache or other style string template), I want to dynamically create some input boxes, and then replace wherever the parameter exists in the template with a 2 way binding of what is in the input box. I am able to create the input boxes, but no idea how I can substitute the values for them into the template (or whether this is even possible in Blazor).

### Example

```
    public class TemplateService
    {
        private List<NameValuePairs> _labels = new List<NameValuePairs>
        {
            new NameValuePairs(){Name="Name", Value="John"},
            new NameValuePairs(){Name="Age", Value="27"},
            new NameValuePairs(){Name="Height", Value=""},
            new NameValuePairs(){Name="Hair Colour", Value=""},
            
        };

        public Task<Template> GetTemplateByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            Template t = new Template() { Labels = _labels, Text = @"Hi, my name is {{Name}}. I am {{Age}} years old" };
            return Task.FromResult(t);
        }
    }
```

```
@inject TemplateService TemplateService

<h3>Text Templates</h3>

@if (template == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var label in template.Labels)
    {
        <label>
            @label.Name :
            <input @bind-value="label.Value" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
        </label>
    }

    <h4>Model</h4>
    @foreach (var l in template.Labels)
    {
        <p>@l.Value</p>
    }

    <h4>Interpolated</h4>
    //HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY A RESULT OF template.text WHEREBY {{Name}} WOULD BE SUBSTITUTED WITH JOHN IN THIS CASE, AND WOULD CHANGE AS THE INPUTBOX FOR NAME IS TYPED IN 
    
}

@code {
    private Template template;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        template = await TemplateService.GetTemplateByIdAsync(1);
    }
}
```

It is the Interpolated bit in the view I am stuck with. I have control over the service so thought about replacing {{Age}} with a function like @FindValueForName("Age"), but not sure if this could be inserted as executable code instead of a literal string. Any thoughts of how this could be achieved in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you can re-structure a bit, you could try this

```
public class Template
{
 public List<NameValuePairs> Labels { get; set; }
 public Func<string> Text { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateService
{
 private List<NameValuePairs> _labels = new List<NameValuePairs>
 {
  new NameValuePairs(){Name="Name", Value="John"},
  new NameValuePairs(){Name="Age", Value="27"},
  new NameValuePairs(){Name="Height", Value=""},
  new NameValuePairs(){Name="Hair Colour", Value=""},
 };

 public string GetListValue(string Name) => _labels.Find(lbl=>lbl.Name==Name).Value;
 public Task<Template> GetTemplateByIdAsync(int id)
 {
  Template t = new Template() 
   { 
    Labels = _labels, 
    Text = () => $@"Hi, my name is {GetListValue("Name")}. I am {GetListValue("Age")} years old" };
    return Task.FromResult(t);
 }
}
```

```
...
<h4>@template.text()</h4>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is getting me on the right lines (completely forgot about dollar syntax). Works great if text is hardcoded. But what if the text is coming from a database ie as a string. Is there a way to make the string execute interpolated?

`...
 //From the DB I get a string and then maybe convert it to be in the following format
 string s = "Hi, my name is {GetListValue(\"Name\")}. I am {GetListValue(\"Age\")} years old";
            Template t = new Template()
            {
                Labels = _labels,
//Not sure
                Text = () => $"{ s }"
            };
...
`